# libGDX html5 project not compeling with swarmconnect

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am having some problems with swarmconnect and libGdx.
I have sucessfully integrated it into my game, but the HTML 5 project is not compiling.
Its is because I have imported the swarm:

```
import com.swarmconnect.Swarm;
```

Is there a way to import only when android is compiling and not in the other projects?[image: The error I get]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lead Dev for Swarm here.  Looks like you should be able to abstract the logic to a class that only gets loaded within Android: http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ApplicationPlatformSpecific